# TextBlock insists on showing &quot; instead of " in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to get a Text description from a website and used this code

```
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string srcCode = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string desc = "";
            rem = @"id=""full_notes"">";
            if (srcCode.IndexOf(rem) != -1)
            {
                desc = srcCode.Remove(0, srcCode.IndexOf(rem) + rem.Length);
                rem = @"<a href=""#"">less</a></span>";
                desc = desc.Remove(desc.IndexOf(rem));
            }
            else
            {
                rem = @"<span>Description:</span>";
                desc = srcCode.Remove(0, srcCode.IndexOf(rem) + rem.Length+15);
                rem = "</div>";
                desc = desc.Remove(desc.IndexOf(rem));
            }
            string rep = @"""";
            desc.Replace("&quot;",rep);
            on.Description = desc;
```

all goes well and I show it in a textblock but the problem comes when the text I get has quotes "" then the textblock would only show &quot instead of the "
anyone knows how to fix this?

Note: I tried to use replace as shown in the code it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `Replace` but not doing anything with the result - strings are immutable in C#, so the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method doesn't change the contents of the existing string. As the documentation states:

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of *oldValue* are replaced by *newValue*.

So you'd need:

```
desc = desc.Replace("&quot;", "\"");
```

Fundamentally though, I think you'd be better off using an HTML parser (e.g. [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)). That should be able to perform this sort of entity replacement for you.